# What's wrong with my ASP.NET MVC routing?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an app that was built on ASP.NET MVC 1 and it's been working fine for a long time now. I needed to add a feature to it and realized that I didn't need the routes that were there because they were handled by the default route.

When I run it on my pc everything works fine with the routes, however, when I upload to the server, it doesn't want to work. I have restarted IIS and even rebooted the server but still not working correctly.

Any ideas? Do I need to do something else?

Comment: any errors? why not add back the unneeded routes?

Comment: Absolutely. Ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: `Do I need to do something else?` yes, you need to show your code.

Comment: well i did add back the routes and it's working but more curious now.

Answer (score 0):

What version of IIS?  If you are using IIS6, you need a wildcard map for routing.

Comment: IIS6, has been running great since beta version

Answer (score 0):

Route debugger will preserve your sanity:  http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx